# Pivot table within sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two table

[stg].[VBAP]

```
SELECT distinct [VBELN]
      ,[POSNR]
FROM [stg].[VBAP]

VBELN   POSNR
0180011720  000010
```

and I have a second table VBPA

```
SELECT [VBELN]
      ,[POSNR]
      ,[PARVW]
      ,[KUNNR]
  FROM [stg].[VBPA]


VBELN   POSNR   PARVW   KUNNR
0180011720  000000  AG  0000506980
0180011720  000000  RE  0000506980
0180011720  000000  RG  0000506980
0180011720  000000  WE  0000506980
0180011720  000000  ZF  0000106790
0180011720  000000  ZU  0000505497
0180011720  000010  ZF  0000108579
0180011720  000010  ZU  0000506980
```

I need to create a pivot table beween the two table in order to get for example as result 
For example, for PARVW  = 'ZU' I have two values for [KUNNR], I must take the value when Posn <> 0

[image]

what I try

```
with VBPA_CTE  ([VBELN],KUNNR,POSNR,PARVW,id)
as(
Select T3.[VBELN],T3.KUNNR ,T3.POSNR ,T3.PARVW

,row_number() over (partition by [PARVW] order by [POSNR] desc )as id
from (
SELECT distinct T1.[VBELN]
      ,T1.[POSNR]
      ,T2.[PARVW]
      ,T2.[KUNNR]
FROM [stg].[VBAP] T1
LEFT JOIN (  select [VBELN]
      ,[POSNR]
      ,[PARVW]
      ,[KUNNR]
      FROM [stg].[VBPA]) T2
      ON T1.[VBELN]=T2.[VBELN]) T3

  where T3.[VBELN] = '0180011720 '
  )
SELECT [VBELN]
  ,[POSNR]
  ,[AG]
  ,[RE]
  ,[RG]
  ,[WE]
  ,[ZU]
 FROM VBPA_CTE

PIVOT (
max(VBPA_CTE.[KUNNR]) 
FOR VBPA_CTE.[PARVW] IN ([AG],[RE],[RG],[WE],[ZU])
) p

  where id=1
```

I didn't get how to link both tables on the same query and how to use the condition when [POSNR] <>0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH VBPA_CTE AS 
(
SELECT [VBELN]
  ,[POSNR]
  ,[PARVW]
  ,[KUNNR]
FROM [stg].[VBPA]
WHERE [POSNR] <> '000000'
)

SELECT [VBELN]
  ,[POSNR]
  ,[AG]
  ,[BP]
  ,[PY]
  ,[SH]
  ,[ZU]
 FROM VBPA_CTE

PIVOT (
max(VBPA_CTE.[KUNNR]) 
FOR VBPA_CTE.[PARVW] IN ([AG],[BP],[PY],[SH],[ZU])
) p
```